# Solution for media presentation - windows 7

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I'm looking for a solution to use a Windows 7 computer to act as a media presenter, with as little third party software as possible.

Idea is to create a PS script or something that scans a networkfolder for media.
The media could be powerpoint presentations, image files and movies.

Ms Office 2010 is installed and VLC is availible to handle movie files.

My company is very restrictive with what software is allowed to be installed, so thats the reason I'm asking.

Edit: question is if anyone could help with some ideas on how to create this solution.
I'm stuck here and I wanted to hears some ideas from you guys.

Comment: Welcome! this is a great list of ideas/limitations, but what are you asking us exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: Well, add some specifics by clicking on the grey edit link underneath your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about writing a command line script which looks for the file in \SERVER\SHOWTHIS for the file of the day and then conditionally executes VLC %1 for movies and POWERPNT %1 for PPTX , then returns to the top? PowerShell is not required.

Include lines like this in your script:

```
:top    
dir /b \\SERVER\SHOWTHIS*.MP4 > %1 && VLC %1
dir /b \\SERVER\SHOWTHIS*.PPTX > %1 && POWERPNT /S %1
goto :top
```

The [/b switch](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/Command-line-switches-for-PowerPoint-2007-and-the-PowerPoint-Viewer-2007-205f1460-098e-42ba-bc6c-310a43d8a2cc?CorrelationId=f21e8ea9-03ba-41d6-8792-46085c331f4a&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) used by DIR strips everything but the file name.
The part after && executes only if the error level is zero, i.e., if such a file was found.
The /S switch in POWERPNT launches the presentation in slideshow mode.

I'd convert a sequence of images into a PPTX or an MP4 instead of trying to have that script figure out how to take a mixed bag of GIF, JPG and PNG and display them in sequence; or, did you wish to show only *one* image if that's all you have?  If it is a sequence of stills, the [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) [Open Source freeware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) will create an MP4 for you.

A [good tutorial](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r92092/ref/win32/win32scripting.html) may help, and a free [WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting) is also available.

VLC also has [documentation](http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html) on its switches if you want something special.

Comment: And, whatever answer you find most useful, please click on the check mark at left to show it worked best for you. This helps us gain Immunity From Kryptonite.